# Не получается установить tensorflow 1.x на python2

Tags: python, tensorflow

На сервере стоит Ubuntu 20.04. Туда установил python3 и  tensorflow 2.3 все нормально установилось. Но при запуске библиотеки Dc_tts, который использует tensorflow появляется ошибка AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'placeholder'. Затем решил установить python2 и tensorflow 1.x. Python 2 установил, но tensorflow 1.x никак не получается установить. Устанавливаю командой pip install tensorflow==1.14.0, пишет что такого пакета нет.

ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.14.1 (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.14.1

Как установить tensorflow 1.x на python2?

Comment: Зачем вам python2?

Comment: Потому что на python3 нельзя установить tensorflow 1.x

Comment: На сайте пакета tensorflow написано, что на python3 можно установить только версию 2.2 и выше

Comment: Где это написано? Отлично всё ставится. Я как раз сомневаюсь, что на python 2 можно поставить.

Comment: На этой странице https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip#system-install написано, что для поддержки python 3.8 требуется TensorFlow 2.2 или новее

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста как Вы установили на python3 tensorflow1.x. Какая версия python у Вас?

Comment: Через pip он должен отлично ставиться. Если на 3.8 не ставится, попробуйте более старую версию python 3.

Comment: А у Вас какая версия python?

Comment: Вот сейчас установил python 3.5 и пытаюсь установить python3 -m pip install tensorflow==1.14, опять та же ошибка ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement tensorflow==1.14.1 (from versions: none) ERROR: No matching distribution found for tensorflow==1.14.1

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38896424/7485582